# Using `header("Location: ...)`

Tags: php, redirect, infinite-loop

I am using a `location()` function call in my configuration file, but it keeps redirecting me to the page I am making to go to in the call to it,

I am doing this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_name']) || !isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']))
{
    header("Location: /login/");
    exit();
}
```

What is the best way to make it so the server knows that it on the login page and not redirect back to this infinitely?

Comment: Setting a header like this `header("Location: ....")` immediately issues a redirect. Can you explain what exactly you want to do? If you wish to redirect the user, when he/she first is logged in correctly, you should move this statement where you validate the user's credentials and set the $_SESSION variables. Otherwise it - of course - can redirect endlessly.

Comment: I want to be able to redirect a user to the /login/ file folder, where the index file is, this is to make sure that they are logged in no matter what to access anything on the site, so I need a way to check if the active page is not the index file on the login directory. Also you can see in the question, I use `header("Location: /login/");` to change the location, the `...` was a space filler

Comment: I think it's not necessary to identify the page itself. If any page scripts are checking the credentials like in your example **but the login.php page** the redirection would only take place when the user is not logged in.

Comment: It's not a page script, it is to be used in conjuction with all front end files a a config file

Comment: Ok, I oversaw that you stated "... in my configuration file". So, I'd recommend to follow the solution from Sam's answer.

Comment: I assume the include is forced by an `auto_prepend_file` statement in the php.ini file. If not, I'd prefer to have the two separated: (a) a config file and (b) a check login file. This would keep the solution more stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way to do this would be to have a `$_SERVER` check to see if the current script is in the `/login/` directory, this could be as follows:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_name']) || !isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']))
{
    if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] !== '/login/index.php')
    {
        header("Location: /login/");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work. On the other hand it has the disadvantage that the script would be bound to a directory and must have the name you are checking for. What when the login page is moved to the directory `/admin/` and is renamed as `login.php`?